# Claims of detection of gravitational waves with an accelerometer

Tags: gravitational-waves, estimation, planets, interferometry, gravitational-wave-detectors

Is this claim:

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/21236/

of detection of gravitational waves with accelerometers legitimate?

I do not know much about this, but given how gravitational waves [form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave#Sources) and the efforts experiments like LIGO take to detect them I have my doubts that this can practically work, even if it was theoretically possible, given the constant noise a body like the earth produces.

I can imagine that accelerometers can be used to calibrate seismic noise prior to data evaluation of an interferometer, but for detection of grav. waves?

Comment: Note that the linked question seems to be about "gravity waves" in Earth's crust. A "gravitational wave" is a distortion of spacetime. A "gravity wave" is a vertical oscillation where gravity provides the restoring force, like water waves which rock your sailboat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that seismic motions affect the interferometers used to detect gravitational waves. Both cause small displacements in the positions of the mirrors, leading to a detectable phase difference when the signals in each interferometer arm are recombined at the beam splitter.

The first is simple seismic activity - both terrestrial and anthropogenic. This is predominantly at low frequencies ($<10$ Hz), but enough would still be present in LIGO's prime 30-500 Hz band to swamp any genuine extra-terrestrial signal if it weren't for the extraordinary damping and suspension systems, which reduce this noise by more than 11 orders of magnitude at 30 Hz.

The second effect cannot easily be avoided. The motion of masses close to the instrument causes fluctuations in the gravitational field that move the test masses. I suppose you could term these low frequency "gravitational waves", but it is not really the same thing, because it is a local effect on one of the test masses rather than a distortion of spacetime affecting the separation of the test masses in one arm. This "gravity gradient noise" is at about the same level as the (damped) seismic noise at around 10 Hz, so is on the verge of producing a detectable signal. At present various instrumentation noise is a bit more important, so confirming the presence of gravity gradient noise is, I think, still not achieved.

Without the exquisite damping of a LIGO-like machine, I can't see how this effect could be detectable.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know the difference between length (unit = m) and acceleration (unit = m/s²)? If any length L changes periodically, L*sin(2*pi*f*t) is valid. The acceleration at the ends of the measuring distance is proportional to L*f² and has no relation to the diameter of a proton.